# In SAS, how can I select all the ID groups which has specific relationship between another variables within the ID group?

Tags: sql, select, syntax, sas

For example, I want to get dataset2 from dataset1.

From dataset1, all IDs, whose value1 of any specific phase is over 10 points greater than the value2 of a previous phase within the IDs (pointed as arrow), were selected in dataset2.

[image: Dataset1]

[image: Dataset2]

I am using SAS EG version and it was impossible for me to make such query.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Post data as text as minimum, posting an image means we need to type out your data to work with it. Additionally please post any attempt you made and review how to ask a question on SO [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in SQL.  To get the rows matching the condition:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tnext
     on tnext.id = t.id and 
        tnext.phase = t.phase + 1
where tnext.value1 > t.value2 + 10;
```

Then you can list the ids using `in` or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select t2.id
               from t t2 join
                    t tnext
                    on tnext.id = t2.id and 
                       tnext.phase = t2.phase + 1
               where tnext.value1 > t2.value2 + 10
              );
```

Comment: Thank you!! With your help I succeeded in selecting the group which I wanted. I also came to know about where-in and join-on clauses.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the difference for each group (`DIF()`)
2. Get IDs where the difference is greater than 10
3. Filter main table

   ```
   data temp;
    set have;
    by id phase;
    /*Part 1*/
    difference = dif(value1);
    if first.id difference = .;
    /*Part 2*/
    if difference > 10 then output;
   run;

   /*Part 3*/
   proc sql;
   create table want as
   select * from have
   where ID in (select distinct ID from temp);
   quit;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.